# whether gluing the faces of tetrahedron in pairs would get a manifold?

Tags: reference-request, manifolds

I think gluing the faces of tetrahedron in pairs would get a manifold.
Because gluing in pairs will make the result of gluing without boundary and there is not Y structure in the result.

But it is not enough for proving it is a manifold. I want to know whether there are any references about the question.

[image]

Comment: Generally the answer is no. To check your space is a manifold you need to check its locally euclidean, and just gluing the faces in pairs is not enough -- imagine a neighbourhood of an edge or vertex.

Comment: In fact ,i think gluing all the faces of several tetrahedron in pairs will yield 3-manifold.There should be not question in the edge or vertex.Do you know any conclusion about this ?

Comment: Unfortunately you're wrong.  There are plenty of ways of constructing such gluings and not getting a manifold in the end.  For example, with a single tetrahedron you can glue the faces together in pairs and get a triangulated space with a single vertex in it.  If you remove the vertex you get something called the Gieseking manifold.  A neighbourhood of the vertex is the cone on a Klein bottle, which isn't locally euclidean.

Comment: Maybe,I construct the space what you say.In above picture ,glue the two a faces and C be glued to B,then glue the two b faces, at last ,the four vertex will be glued together.but i really can't image it. what book i should read?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can read about this question in Thurston's book, **The geometry and topology of 3-manifolds**. It turns out to be subtle, but I won't spoil the ending for you.

Comment: thank you ,i will read it .

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have not one (3-dimensional) tetrahedron but several, otherwise it is too boring. Then, by gluing 2-faces in pairs you will get a *pseudomanifold*, moreover, it is a manifold away from vertices. However, it need not be a manifold in general. In order to get a manifold it is necessary and sufficient that links of vertices are 2-dimensional spheres.

Comment: what mean the links of vertices? Is it the line connecting different vertices? How does it to be 2-dimensional?

Comment: @lanse2pty: To define the link of a vertex you first takes 2nd barycenteric subdivision of you complex to make it simplicial. Then you apply the standard notion of link which you can find in any algebraic topology book: Take the star of the vertex and in this star you consider the sub complex of faces disjoint from the vertex. The link is 2 dimensional in this case, not 1 dimensional.